Which episode of "Star Trek: The Next Generation" has a discussion about the shape of a glass?
In which episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation do Picard, Data, and La Forge discuss the strange shape of a glass with a replicated drink? I believe it happened in the meeting room and they discuss whether the shape is an error of the replicator.

It doesn't exactly match your description, but in "Hollow Pursuits" a glass is replicated with a deformed shape in Ten Forward. Data, Barclay and LaForge discuss it in Engineering (including whether it's a replicator error), but they do take it to the bridge where Riker and Picard also examine it.

Yes, the description I provided was incorrect, it was Data, Barclay, and LaForge in Engineering.
